# What's the API for declaring initialValues asyncronously in redux-form?

Tags: redux-form, react-apollo, apollo-client

Consider [this example](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/pull/136/files#diff-5a60ee56da2bb34d287b107dc03083edR187) using version `5.3.2`:

```
@reduxForm({
   form: 'contact',
 }, (state, ownProps) => ({ // check the current component's props
   initialValues: ownProps.data.loading 
     ? '' // nothing if still loading
     : ownProps.data.allPeople.people[0].name, // data if done fetching
 }))
```

[The documented demo code for version `>6`](http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/initializeFromState/) doesn't show this function callback pattern as a possibility:

```
// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm)

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }               // bind account loading action creator
)(InitializeFromStateForm)
```

Is the first pattern still possible? If so, how does it work? Is it documented anywhere? I see that [I'm given an `initialize` dispatcher](http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/ActionCreators.md/#-initialize-form-string-data-object-keepdirty-boolean-options-keepdirty-boolean-keepsubmitsucceeded-boolean-) in my component props. Is that the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give you an apollo specific answer, although you didn't mention apollo at all in your question, just in the tags. Looks like you meant to.

When you wrap your component with apollo, remap the prop names to be under initialValues, so redux-form can pick it up, for example:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
import { gql, graphql } from 'react-apollo'

const currentUser = gql`
  query viewer {
    viewer {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`

export default graphql(currentUser, {
  props: ({ ownProps, data: { loading, viewer } }) => ({
    loading,
    initialValues: {
      firstName: viewer && viewer.firstName,
      lastName: viewer && viewer.lastName,
    },
  })
)(MyComponent)
```